# Physics of Neuroscience - Action potential

Tags: potential, voltage, definition, biophysics

I am confused about how to understand action potential in the context of physics.

1. Are [action potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential) and [potential difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage) synonymous? If so why is it stated that an action potential 'travels' down the neuron?
2. What actually travels down the neuron? Electrons like in a circuit, or something slightly different?

Answer (score 2):

> Are 'action potential' and 'potential difference' synonymous? 
>   If so why is it stated that an action potential 'travels' down the neuron?

The potential difference is what you can measure (with a volt-meter) at a certain point across the membrane.

The action potential is the *shape* of the potential difference in time and space (the traveling peak). It lasts only for some milliseconds
at any given point of the axon, and travels down at high speed.

See this animated picture from [Wikipedia: Action Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential):

[image: Action Potential]

> What actually travels down the neuron?
>   Electrons like in a circuit, or something slightly different?

The action potential (the peak-like shape) travels down the neuron.
The individual ions ($Na^+, K^+, ...$) move only
very short distances back and forth across the membrane.